# How to add multiple models in a scene and later retrieve it using scene recognition in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

Every time I touch the screen the same model appears in screen.If I touch the screen at five different positions the models gets instantiated at 5 touched positions on the screen.It gets saved in the cloud later.When I load the saved map and scans the same place it recognizes the scene but only one model is showing in the screen.I am adding an "arrow" as model.I will provide the code below.

So how does the position gets saved here?.Only single model position gets saved?Why other position models are not showing?Is it because I am using the same model.?How to save other models position?

If I add the code below the lines (//if line below added) the implementation works.Many shapes will be instantiated on touch and later can be loaded even after the app is closed.

```
bool HitTestWithResultType(ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
{
    List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().HitTest(point, resultTypes);

    if (hitResults.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var hitResult in hitResults)
        {

            Debug.Log("Got hit!");

            Vector3 position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition(hitResult.worldTransform);
            Quaternion rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation(hitResult.worldTransform);

            //Transform to placenote frame of reference (planes are detected in ARKit frame of reference)
            Matrix4x4 worldTransform = Matrix4x4.TRS(position, rotation, Vector3.one);
            Matrix4x4? placenoteTransform = LibPlacenote.Instance.ProcessPose(worldTransform);

            Vector3 hitPosition = PNUtility.MatrixOps.GetPosition(placenoteTransform.Value);
            Quaternion hitRotation = PNUtility.MatrixOps.GetRotation(placenoteTransform.Value);

            // add shape
            AddShape(hitPosition, hitRotation);


            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


//-----------------------------------
// Update function checks for hittest
//-----------------------------------

void Update()
{

    // Check if the screen is touched
    //-----------------------------------

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began  )
        {
            if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == null)
            {

                Debug.Log("Not touching a UI button. Moving on.");

                // add new shape
                var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                ARPoint point = new ARPoint
                {
                    x = screenPosition.x,
                    y = screenPosition.y
                };

                // prioritize reults types
                ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent,
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedHorizontalPlane,
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedVerticalPlane,
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                };

                foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                {
                    if (HitTestWithResultType(point, resultType))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Found a hit test result");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void OnSimulatorDropShape()
{
    Vector3 dropPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 0.3f;
    Quaternion dropRotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;

    AddShape(dropPosition, dropRotation);

}

//-------------------------------------------------
// All shape management functions (add shapes, save shapes to metadata etc.
//-------------------------------------------------

public void AddShape(Vector3 shapePosition, Quaternion shapeRotation)
{
//if line below added
   // System.Random rnd = new System.Random(); 
//if line below added
    //PrimitiveType type = (PrimitiveType)rnd.Next(0, 3);

    ShapeInfo shapeInfo = new ShapeInfo();
    shapeInfo.px = shapePosition.x;
    shapeInfo.py = shapePosition.y;
    shapeInfo.pz = shapePosition.z;
    shapeInfo.qx = shapeRotation.x;
    shapeInfo.qy = shapeRotation.y;
    shapeInfo.qz = shapeRotation.z;
    shapeInfo.qw = shapeRotation.w;
//if line below added
   // shapeInfo.shapeType = type.GetHashCode();
    shapeInfoList.Add(shapeInfo);

    GameObject shape = ShapeFromInfo(shapeInfo);
    shapeObjList.Add(shape);
}


public GameObject ShapeFromInfo(ShapeInfo info)
{
    //if line below added
//GameObject shape = GameObject.CreatePrimitive((PrimitiveType)info.shapeType);

//Instead of
    GameObject shape =Instantiate(arrow);   

    shape.transform.position = new Vector3(info.px, info.py, info.pz);
    shape.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(info.qx, info.qy, info.qz, info.qw);
    shape.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    shape.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mShapeMaterial;
    shape.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = Color.yellow;
    return shape;
}
```

Comment: please clarify: you want the user to be able to save the level with the arrows placed where they put them  OR you want to save the level as you set it up with the arrows where you put them?    in short is this a user save game we need to implement? or are you just setting up your scene?

Answer (score 1):

In HitTestWithResultType() you have a return in the foreach, so when one iteration is done, the code exits the method.
Basically you do only one iteration in the foreach every time you call the method.
move the return 2 lines below after the closing bracket.

I guess everybody need another pair of eyes :)

Comment: @nigimi the problem is if i add line..GameObject shape = GameObject.CreatePrimitive((PrimitiveType)info.shapeType); instead of GameObject shape =Instantiate(arrow);      and uncomment a few lines .     everything works fine.There are many shapes getting added ,saving and loading the map with all the models even  after the app is closed  .

Comment: Sorry, did not understand that.